# Convert a tf.float32 to a regular python float

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

This is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

loss = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()

a = loss(y_true=tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0]), y_pred=tf.constant([2.0, 2.0, 4.0]))
print(a)

b = tf.constant([2.0, 2.0, 4.0])[0]
a = loss(y_true=tf.constant([1.0], dtype=tf.float32), y_pred=tf.constant([b], dtype=tf.float32)) #error occurs here
print(a)
```

This is the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "test.py", line 9, in 
>       a = loss(y_true=tf.constant([1.0], dtype=tf.float32), y_pred=tf.constant([b], dtype=tf.float32))
>     File "D:\documenten\programs\Python\3.6.2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 227, in constant
>       allow_broadcast=True)
>     File "D:\documenten\programs\Python\3.6.2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 235, in _constant_impl
>       t = convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
>     File "D:\documenten\programs\Python\3.6.2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 96, in convert_to_eager_tensor
>       return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
>   ValueError: TypeError: Scalar tensor has no `len()`

In this exemple I can't use 'b' to put in an other tensor, but the regular float works just fine.
Is there a method change a tf.float32 to a regular python float?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a simple python float:`float(b)`

Although, I think your error occurs mostly because you are trying to make `b` a `tf.constant` when it already is a `tf.constant`.

To convert tensor's data type you can use [tf.cast](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dtypes/cast).

So your above code also works in such scenario:

```
loss = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()

a = loss(y_true=tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0]), y_pred=tf.constant([2.0, 2.0, 4.0]))
print(a)

b = tf.constant([2.0, 2.0, 4.0])[0]
b = tf.cast(b, dtype=tf.float32)

a = loss(y_true=tf.constant([1.0], dtype=tf.float32), y_pred=[b]) 
print(a)
```